# Duplicate current powershell session in a new window

Tags: windows, powershell

Is it possible to duplicate a powershell session in a new window? I often find that I've created environment variables, activated a specific python virtualenvironment, defined one-off functions, custom prompt, etc. and it would be handy to duplicate those specific, one-off details of the current session into another session in another window.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Powershell profile. In the profile you can have all of those functions, variables etc. Basically every time you open a powershell window, you can load your custom powershell profile which in turn will also load your settings as defined. Please see this link: [Powershell profile](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.10.windowspowershell.aspx]).

Comment: That totally does not answer the question as asked : "it would be handy to duplicate those specific, one-off details of the current session into another session". Profiles are for things you will always want set; this is a different scenario.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing I'm aware of, out of the box, that will do this. You could write a script to dump all of the things you care about, and then paste those into your new window.

```
get-childitem -path env:
```

will show all your environment variables.

```
Get-Variable
```

will show your powershell variables.

```
Get-ChildItem -path function:
```

will show all functions. If you have a naming convention for your custom ones, you could filter on just those.